# MySQL Fetch Website Stats For All Days

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net, datetime, statistics

Every time a new visitor visits my site, they are logged into a database. I have been able to select the number of users on a specific day within the past seven days by using this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Hits, DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS HitDay FROM(stats) WHERE Date >= DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) GROUP BY DATE(Date) ORDER BY Date ASC
```

The issue is that I have to graph this data in a chart within VB as part of a project, and if there were not hits on a specific date, then there is a gap between two dates on the chart. I want to know if its possible to return all dates within the past seven dates with a 0 on the `Hits` column if there hasn't been any visitors. The interval can change too, so it could range from 1 to 31.

Maybe this could be done with a procedure or function? Any ideas would be great, but I am trying to not fill in the gaps within VB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate the 7 days and LEFT JOIN it with stats like below

```
SELECT COUNT(stats.date) AS Hits, DATE_FORMAT(days.Date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS HitDay 
FROM
   (SELECT CURDATE() as date
    UNION SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
    UNION SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
    UNION SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
    UNION SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 DAY
    UNION SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY
    UNION SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY
    )days
LEFT JOIN stats ON days.date = stats.date
GROUP BY DATE(days.Date) ORDER BY days.Date ASC
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4dfc3/3/0)

If your interval changes maybe specify more like below (up 128 days) and just change the condition `< 7` to whatever your interval is

```
SELECT COUNT(stats.date) AS Hits, DATE_FORMAT(days.Date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS HitDay 
FROM
   (SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 
     (d1.value+d2.value+d3.value+d4.value+
      d5.value+d6.value+d7.value) day as date
    FROM (SELECT 0 as value UNION SELECT 1)d1,
         (SELECT 0 as value UNION SELECT 2)d2,
         (SELECT 0 as value UNION SELECT 4)d3,
         (SELECT 0 as value UNION SELECT 8)d4,
         (SELECT 0 as value UNION SELECT 16)d5,
         (SELECT 0 as value UNION SELECT 32)d6,
         (SELECT 0 as value UNION SELECT 64)d7
    WHERE (d1.value+d2.value+d3.value+d4.value+
      d5.value+d6.value+d7.value) < 7
    )days
LEFT JOIN stats ON days.date = DATE(stats.date)
GROUP BY DATE(days.Date) ORDER BY days.Date ASC
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4dfc3/7/0)

Comment: Is it possible to create something like a loop as the interval could change

Comment: This isn't working for me though, it returns a 0 in the `Hits` column when my original code will return a 3 or a 6

Comment: maybe the join isn't working because your date has a time value maybe join `ON days.date = DATE(stats.date)`

Comment: i just updated my answer to include a version to specify more days and you can change the interval `< 7` check it out.

Comment: Thanks for that! Just one last issue, I need to include the code `WHERE NewUser = 'True'`, but my amateur skills aren't really suited to this

Comment: just add that before the `GROUP BY` it should just work.

Comment: oh i forgot we're doing a LEFT JOIN so you want to add `OR stats.NewUser IS NULL` like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6be08/5/0

Comment: or you can add it as part of the JOIN condition like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6be08/6/0 (adding it as part the JOIN condition makes more sense to me, but it's totally up to you).